# HTTP Error 503 on SharePoint 2013 Farm

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-503

I have the following issue on our SharePoint Farm

> ### Service Unavailable
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

When this message appears, a page refresh by the user does help. The message comes up only for some users, not for all of them.

How I can troubleshoot this issue?

Note: there are no critical issues in the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your IIS instance isn't started or starting. It happens from time to time and usually restarting the server instance will resolve it. If not you're going to look at the SharePoint Logs. [This tool](https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/) will greatly help with that.

Given that it's not showing all the time I would anticipate that you have two web front ends and you will need to perform these checks across both of them.